# How to ensure database isolation when having multiple python scripts interacting with it?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a python script that runs as a cron job, requests data from an api and uses it to update a postgresql database using psycopg2.
I want to create a new python script that would only be executed manually (and occasionally) and that will also be updating that same database (same tables too). What is the best way to ensure that there will be no conflicts between multiple python scripts updating the same database ?

Comment: Why does this matter? The database is designed to handle concurrent operations regardless of source

Comment: There is an entire chapter about concurrency: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

Comment: So I could just write my second python script without explicitly addressing this issue, and the concurrent operations would still be handled by the database ? Cool, thanks !

Comment: It's definitely possible to do it wrong, despite the database provides all the tools you need to avoid conflicts and data races. If you're only inserting new rows you should be fine though.

Comment: If you need to update existing rows then avoid this: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/

Comment: With the amount of detail you gave, all i can recommend is `SERIALIZABLE` isolation and retry on serialization failures.